Residue theorem with an undefined order pole
Good afternoon everyone,
I have a question about the application of residues theorem that is appearing in my current work (about Diffusion Theory using Langmuir Model but in cylindrical coordinates).

I used Laplace transform and ended with the following function :
$$\bar{N}(r,p) = \frac{n_\infty}{p}\frac{\gamma}{p+\beta}\frac{I_0(r\times W(p))}{I_0(a\times W(p))}$$
with $n_\infty$, $a$, $\gamma$ and $\beta$ constants, and $I_0$ modified Bessel function. $W(p)$ is defined as :
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{D}\left(p+\frac{p\gamma}{p+\beta}\right)}$$
with $D$ a diffusion constant.
To go back from the Laplace transform $\bar{N}$ to the original $n$, I need to use Bromwich integral, therefore need to find the residues.
My problem here is for the pole defined at $p = -\beta$, since $W(p)$ isnt defined either for $p = -\beta$.
In the original paper by Carter named "Langmuir-Type Model for Anomalous Moisture Diffusion In Composite Resins", the same methodology is applied in cartesian coordinates.
Author also have the same situation I presented above, with a pole that is not defined inside a function, but a result is shown.
Therefore, I guess that there is a way to deal with this kind of problem that I dont know.

Thank you for your attention and for any advice / help you might provide. Feel free to ask for complementary informations.
I apologize for my english level and for the mathematical notations that are not very rigourous.

It will be a branch point, not a pole. If you change coordinates, you’re looking at $\sqrt u$ at $u=0$.

I guess ${\tt I}_{0}$ is a $\displaystyle\color{red}{\underline{constant}}$.

@TedShifrin Thank you for the time you took to read my question and for answering to it. I didnt know about branch point and will take a deeper look at it. I am sorry for the naivety of my question, but if $p$ tends to $-\beta$, wouldnt here $\sqrt{u}$ tends to $\infty$ ?

Note that the square root function is not analytic at $0$, so its reciprocal does not have a Laurent expansion at $0$.
